# Product Images are all different sizes? How to fix

Tags: magento2.3, product-images

My product images or certain pages are all different sizes. Anyone know why? Image below.

[image]

Comment: You can set a fix size to image by using html attribute to img tag like <img src="web.jpg" width="460" height="580" alt="web">

Comment: Where do I set Fix size to image at in Admin?

Comment: To make my question more clear. Where can I put the html tags at in Admin? Its only happening on certain images. Which I find strange.

Comment: are you using any theme ?

Comment: yes. Smart wave Porto Theme.  I believe it has something to do with image size.  if I make the image a square it works. But otherwise it shows really huge.  I'm not sure why because width and height set at 200px.

Comment: That is if I edit it in a photo editor on my computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento uses the file called `view.xml` which is maintained at the theme level of the application.

So for example, if you are using the default theme luma you should find the `view.xml` in `vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/etc/view.xml`

In this file, you would see node inside the node.

The dimension of the images is maintained here under the node.

The id attribute value of the node is referenced in the code base.

```
<image id="product_page_main_image" type="image">
        <width>700</width>
        <height>560</height>
    </image>
    <image id="product_page_main_image_default" type="image">
        <width>700</width>
        <height>560</height>
    </image>
```

You can define your custom `view.xml` in your theme and define width & height as per your requirement.

In case of changing/overwriting the values of the `view.xml` file you need to completely copy the entire `view.xml` file to your custom theme and change the values.

`view.xml` does not have a node value fallback system, means if a value of a node is not present in you custom theme's `view.xml` it will not fallback to its parent theme's `view.xml` value, that's why entire file needs to be copied.

Once the values changes have been done, you will have to run

```
php bin/magento catalog:images:resize
```

This will regenerate the new image sizes.

Answer (score 0):

> Once check the your product image path at frontend side, it's take the path in
> **pub/media/catalog/product/cache** or not.
>
> if it's not take the path of **pub/media/catalog/product/cache** then it's display the your original product image from path: **pub/media/catalog/product**